# Internal clojure function to convert non-alphanumeric symbols to java class names

Tags: clojure

Im looking for the internal implementation of clojure turning non-alphanumerics into words.

For example clojure.core/assoc! gets compiled to assoc_BANG_ and so on, where does the compiler do its conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 user=> (munge "assoc!")
"assoc_BANG_"
```

---

```
user=> (source munge)
(defn munge [s]
  ((if (symbol? s) symbol str) (clojure.lang.Compiler/munge (str s))))
```

Comment: Would you know where the compiler uses this?

Comment: grep -n munge -r source_path